# Pyodbc Error 07002 - Count field incorrect or syntax error - Insert Data From Form

Tags: python, sql-server, forms, flask, pyodbc

I've been building a webapp for the HR department which will (hopefully) include the ability for staff to submit timesheets and I have become stuck when trying to submit a timesheet. The connection string is working as I can see other data from the database. I have been working through errors but this 07002 error is one I can't work out what is causing it.

I've tried two different ways to get this working. Here is the first attempt in my app.py file -

```
@app.route('/timesheet', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def employee_timesheet():
    if request.method == "POST":
        employee_id = request.form['employee_id']
        department = request.form['department']
        mondaystart = request.form['mondaystart']
        mondayend = request.form['mondayend']
        tuesdaystart = request.form['tuesdaystart']
        tuesdayend = request.form['tuesdayend']
        wednesdaystart = request.form['wednesdaystart']
        wednesdayend = request.form['wednesdayend']
        thursdaystart = request.form['thursdaystart']
        thursdayend = request.form['thursdayend']
        fridaystart = request.form['fridaystart']
        fridayend = request.form['fridayend']
        saturdaystart = request.form['saturdaystart']
        saturdayend = request.form['saturdayend']        
        result = request.form
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()          
        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO dbo.submitted_timesheet (employee_id, department, mondaystart, mondayend, tuesdaystart, tuesdayend, wednesdaystart, wednesdayend, thursdaystart, thursdayend, fridaystart, fridayend, saturdaystart, saturdayend,) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''')                
        cnxn.commit()
        flash("Your form was successfully submitted")
        print("Form data submitted")
        return redirect (url_for('success.html', result=result))
        
    return render_template("staff_timesheets.html")
```

The other way then is -

```
@app.route('/timesheet', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def employee_timesheet():
    if request.method == "POST":
        employee_id = request.form['employee_id']
        department = request.form['department']
        mondaystart = request.form['mondaystart']
        mondayend = request.form['mondayend']
        tuesdaystart = request.form['tuesdaystart']
        tuesdayend = request.form['tuesdayend']
        wednesdaystart = request.form['wednesdaystart']
        wednesdayend = request.form['wednesdayend']
        thursdaystart = request.form['thursdaystart']
        thursdayend = request.form['thursdayend']
        fridaystart = request.form['fridaystart']
        fridayend = request.form['fridayend']
        saturdaystart = request.form['saturdaystart']
        saturdayend = request.form['saturdayend']
        insert_query = '''INSERT INTO submitted_timesheet (employee_id, department, mondaystart, mondayend, tuesdaystart, tuesdayend, wednesdaystart, wednesdayend, thursdaystart, thursdayend, fridaystart, fridayend, saturdaystart, saturdayend,) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'''        
        result = request.form
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()           
        cursor.execute(insert_query, values)                
        cnxn.commit()
        flash("Your form was successfully submitted")
        print("Form data submitted")
        return redirect (url_for('success.html', result=result))
        
    return render_template("staff_timesheets.html")
```

If I submit a timesheet, I get the Pyodbc error in the title. Everything matches up in terms of column names and types. The HTML form should be fine too but can post it if needed for context.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: The insert statements in `cursor.execute` have a lot of placeholders but you're not actually supplying the required values as the second (array) parameter to `cursor.execute`.

Comment: Sorry, @AlwaysLearning, that was a typo in the codeblock here rather than what was in my app.py file. I've updated the codeblock. Thanks for that.

Comment: Presumably `values` is meant to be your array of 14 required values from the request form... but where you do define and assign it?

Comment: So define it outside of the insert_query?
Something like - 
values = '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?'
Thanks for replying!